# Wordpress: Change the name of the parameters of all users called 'Roles'

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to change the name of the parameter of all users called 'Roles' to 'Levels'.

I already tried to find it in the database of the website but nowhere this row with parameters was.

Is it possible to change this in this table of all users?[image]

Also, I'm trying to change it there when the admin creating new users.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the column label for user table using `manage_users_columns` hook.

```php
add_action( 'manage_users_columns', 'bks_change_user_column_role_to_levels', 10, 1);

function bks_change_user_column_role_to_levels( $data ) {
    if( isset($data['role']) ) {
        $data['role'] = 'Levels';
    }

    return $data;
}
```

This would change your table label from `Role` to `Levels`.

[image: Role changed to Levels Table]

---

I couldn't find any hooks to change the label for user-new page. But we can use a hacky way to get this done as well. Check the code below.

```php
if ($pagenow=='user-new.php') { 

    add_filter( 'gettext', 'bks_change_role_to_levels', 20, 3 );

    function bks_change_role_to_levels( $translated_text, $text, $domain ){
        if ($translated_text == 'Role') {
            $translated_text = 'Levels';
        }

        return $translated_text;
    }
}
```

This would change your field label from `Role` to `Levels`.

[image: Change Role to Levels User Add page]

---

The code above is tested and WORKS.